# can build using visual studio ide but cannot build using devenv.com

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build-process, cruisecontrol.net, devenv

i'm using VS 2008. I can compile my solution using the IDE successfully. However, when I try to build it using devenv.com, it fails saying that "ERROR: Cannot find outputs of project output group '(unable to determine name)'.  Either the group, its configuration, or its project may have been removed from the solution." while building a .vdproj setup project.

A similar problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586836/error-when-using-devenv-command-line-but-not-using-ide)

any ideas to fix this?
thx

Edit: Actually cruisecontrol.net tries to build the solution using devenv.com. Here is the devenv section i use in ccnet.config:

```
<devenv>
      <solutionfile>xxxxx.sln</solutionfile>
      <configuration>Debug</configuration>
      <buildtype>Build</buildtype>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</executable>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>60000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
      <version>VS2008</version>
    </devenv>
```

Comment: Please don't make us guess at the command line you use.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an invalid argument in the command line you pass to devenv.com.

Does it work ok if you create a new solution with a simple hello world project?

Cheers,

Sebastiaan

Comment: yes devenv.com builds another solution successfully. maybe it's something to do with the .vdproj project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the MSBuild task instead of VisualStudio? I have always had better results with MSBuild, especially as it means you do not need VisualStudio installed on your Build Machine.

Here is a generic config based off what I use:

```
<msbuild>
    <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>D:\dev\your\path\</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>xxxx.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/v:m /noconlog /p:Configuration=Debug</buildArgs>
    <targets>Build</targets>
    <!--<logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCNet.dll</logger>-->
    <!-- If you dont have that logger for CruiseControl, you should try it :) -->
</msbuild>
```

If this does not work, you can also run it from a command line:

```
>cd "D:\dev\your\path\"
>D:
>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe /v:m /p:Configuration=Debug xxxxx.sln
```

You can change the `v` (`Verbosity`) flag to something higher to get more output if you need ([see msdn article on MSBuild here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)).

Comment: Guess I had tried that too, but I can't remember exactly right now. Now I've switched platforms to Mac, so unfortunately I can't re-try that, but I hope your answer helps someone else. Thx Pondidum :)